# Explorer.exe keeps trying to Visit Suspicious Website

Tags: windows-explorer, malware, malware-removal

Today, I have been receiving pop-ups from Malwarebytes roughly every 20 minutes telling me that it blocked `C:\Windows\explorer.exe` from attempting to visit `appexsports.trafficmanager.net`. A full scan with neither Malwarebytes nor Windows Defender does not find anything. Reading online, this issue seems to come with an array of browser hijacking issues, none of which I have experienced beyond what seems to be the hijacking of `explorer.exe`. Does anyone know how to remove this?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues on my windows machine couple weeks ago. I fixed my machine by removing malicious programs from "Programs and features" & Startup programs list.

I would suggest to start with looking at the list of programs installed on your machine, see if there are any program which you don't recognize and then look at installed directory of them.

I would also look at the programs  which gets loaded during startup by navigating to "Task Manager>Startup Tab" (in windows 8 and above), see if there are any program you don't recognize.

If you Identify any Suspicious program in the startup list, disable them and reboot your machine. See if you still get "Warning messages".

If you have any good "System Restore" point available, restoring would help as well I guess.

Comment: I am creeping around my hard drive and I have not yet found anything suspicious.

Comment: Can you please check extensions added your browsers as well.